# Most pythonic way to relocate a path to a new root directory

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
a = "/my/absolute/path"
b = "my/relative/path"
root = "/new/root/dir"
print relocate_path(a, root)
print relocate_path(b, root)
```

I would like to get:

```
/new/root/dir/my/absolute/path
/new/root/dir/my/relative/path
```

How to effectively implement `relocate_path` in a pythonic way? Is there something like that in the standard library? (I have tried in [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html), but found nothing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `os.path.join` for relative paths. In case of absolute path I think the best thing you can do is stripping the leading slash.

Something like this:

```
def relocate_path(new_root, path):
    return os.path.join(new_root, path.lstrip('/'))
```

To get a path relative to root given an absolute path you can also do:

```
>>> os.path.relpath('/absolute/path', '/')
'absolute/path'
```

but I don't think it's more crossplatform than just stripping the slash. I've tried playing with `relpath` on Windows a bit and I should say I have no idea how it works.

Comment: So you mean something like: `def relocate_path(new_root, path): return os.path.join(new_root, path.lstrip('/'))`

Comment: Put it in your answer (is kind of funny to put it in my question), and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Just now I wrote a small python script, i don't know whether it can help you.

```
import re

def relocate_path(path,root):
    pattern = re.compile(r'^/')
    match = pattern.match(path)
    if match:
        return (root+path)
    else:
        return (root+"/"+path)
```

Comment: `re` is overkill. A simple lstrip is enough.

Comment: ok.I haven't used istrip before, i will try it, thanks gonvaled!

Comment: And concatenating paths with `+` is a bad style.